# Ajax and php - sending javascript array to php

Tags: php, ajax

i try to send data to my php scripts but i think i miss something.

First of all,

```
   function deleteData2()
    {
        var artistIds = new Array();

        $(".p16 input:checked").each(function(){
            artistIds.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });


       $.post('/json/crewonly/deleteDataAjax2', JSON.stringify({'artistIds': artistIds}),function(response){
        if(response=='ok')
            alert(artistIds);
    });


    }
```

Above code is my js file. i have artistIds in var artistIds. My goal is sending this array to my php script.In order to that, i make it json , i mean encode it with  JSON.stringify

then in php side, i use below code.However, $array is always null. What might be the reason ?

```
public function deleteDataAjax2() {

        $array=json_decode($_POST['artistIds']);

        if (isset($array))
            $this->sendJSONResponse('ok');

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `print_r( $_POST )`? It should be the #1 step in any situation like this.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't believe you; `$_POST` is always an array, even if no post data is sent. (Don't print `$array` but the whole `$_POST` variable.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing the data as a raw string of JSON, but your PHP is trying to find that string by parsing the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and then looking at the `artistIds` key.

Assuming the array is flat: Forget JSON. You don't need it.

```
$.post('/json/crewonly/deleteDataAjax2', {'artistIds': artistIds},function(response){
```

And:

```
$array = $_POST['artistIds'];
```

If the array isn't flat, then:

```
$.post('/json/crewonly/deleteDataAjax2', 
       { json: JSON.stringify({'artistIds': artistIds}) },
       function(response){
```

And (with suitable error checking added):

```
$json = $_POST['json'];
$data = json_decode($json);
$artists = $data['artistIds'];
```